# Is it possible to set SSG and SSR for each page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to know how to set SSG and SSR on a page-by-page basis, not on a project-by-project basis.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "switching". What would be the use-case to call SSG once again after the hydration phase?

Comment: @kissu
excuse me. I'm not good at English and the expression may have been wrong.
For example, the top page is created with SSG, and the other pages are created with SSR.

Comment: What would be the benefit of this? Can you explain such use case?

Comment: @kissu
I'm guessing that by setting the top page to SSG instead of SSR, the top page can be displayed faster.
I think that performance can be improved by creating pages that require dynamic processing with SSR and static pages with SSG.

Comment: Backend generation (either SSG or SSR) should still be super fast, not a thing to worry with IMO. And it's only happening upon initial fetch, then it's just an SPA, so you will not feel a lot of difference afterwards. Also, SSG can totally do dynamic, it is just not able to do a Twitter-like dynamic. Performance can be improved in a lot of various ways. which are more impacting (mainly JS blocking the thread).

Comment: Thank you very much.
Thanks to your advice, I realized that I don't have to worry too much about performance.
It helped me to get deeper about Nuxt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxt does not support hybrid SSG or SSR modes, hence why this is defined globally and not per component.
At the end, performance should be as good with either SSG or SSR and you can probably generate most of your content with SSG.

More rendering modes will probably be announced during [NuxtNation](https://nuxtnation.com/) so feel free to join.

In the meantime, I know that Next.js does have some flexibility in the way that it allows to still request some routes from the server (not only using client-side queries).
It is called [getServerSideProps (Server-side Rendering)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) and you can get more context in this [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/lindsaykwardell/status/1420549075900919810).

Nuxt do not have this kind of thing tho.

Comment: Kissu, I have a similar situation in my project. So SSG for faster load but need SSR for dynamic pages that their content are changed more often in backend.   Nuxt SSG mode is configured to generate some pages. but other pages need to be dynamic. I decided to use `target:static` to generate the files and then change it to `target:server`  and `npm run build` and then `npm run start`. So now I have some static files to be served with nginx and a nuxt server (SSR). I can set reverse proxy in nginx to pass the request to Nuxt Server is no static file found. Do you think this is a good practice?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki you can have some hybrid modes nowadays with Nuxt3: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering ISR is a good one if you do not want to regenerate all of the static pages from scratch, got some methods like SWR too. Otherwise yes, there was a practice of double-building like that in the past. Probably not the best solution now that we have something more native in Nuxt3 but was a decent enough workaround back in the time yes.